# Unable to get the upcoming events for custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query

I have custom post ='events' and there is custom field 'event-start-date' for each events. I want to show the upcoming events for which I am using the following code.

```
$date_today = time();
                 $meta_query_args=array('key' => 'event-start-date',
                                        'value' => $date_today,
                                        'compare' => '>',
                                       );    
                 $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
                                             'post_type' => 'events',
                                             'posts_per_page' => 5 ,
                                             'meta_key'   =>   'event-start-date',
                                             'orderby' => 'event-start-date',
                                             'order'=>'desc',
                                             'meta_query' => $meta_query_args
                                              )
                                    );
```

But this is giving me all the posts, even those which are not upcoming i.e `'event-start-date' < $date_today`.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just changed the query a little

```
 $meta_query_args=array(
                        'relation'  =>   'AND',
                        array(
                             'key' => 'event-start-date',
                             'value' => $date_today,
                             'compare' => '<',
                             )
                        ); 
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
                                             'post_type' => 'events',
                                             'posts_per_page' => 5 ,
                                             'meta_key'   =>   'event-start-date',
                                             'orderby' => 'event-start-date',
                                             'order'=>'desc',
                                             'meta_query' => $meta_query_args
                                              )
                                    );

                      if($loop->have_posts()): while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

but can anybody please explain me what 'relation'  =>   'AND' is doing

Comment: See [Codex - WP_Query: Custom Fields Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for details on the `relation` argument of the `meta_query` parameter.